# What's the standard way of adding a fade-out effect when using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

Is there a recommended or standard way of adding a fade-out animation to an element (say a button or div) when using Angular? I'd like some popup text that reappears when users perform an action, but then fades away after a set time of 0.5 second or 1 second.

Comment: yes there is. take a look at this blog http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/25/easy-animations-for-angularjs-with-animate-css.aspx and https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/. basically, you need to inject ngAnimate into your app and create animation classes which utilize the ng-show ng-hide properties

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h58wsxcw/ take a look